# Spring MVC Restful 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: xml, json, rest, spring-mvc

I am working on building a RESTful API with Spring MVC that can return both JSON and XML depending on what the client wants to work with. However I am getting weird behavior, 406 Not Accepted error.

`http://localhost:8080/gender` returns 406 now matter how I set the Accept header.

`http://localhost:8080/gender/1` works without setting Accept, and with text/xml and application/xml

However application/json and text/json return 406 Not Accepted

Any ideas why?

Relevant code below

Controller

```
package net.jkratz.bloodpressure.api.controller;

import net.jkratz.bloodpressure.api.model.Gender;
import net.jkratz.bloodpressure.api.repository.GenderRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/gender")
public class GenderController {

    @Inject
    GenderRepository genderRepository;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = {"","/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Gender>> getGenders(@RequestHeader("Accept") String acceptHeader) {
        logger.info("Serving resource for Accept header: {}", acceptHeader);
        List<Gender> genders = genderRepository.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(genders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Gender> getGender(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestHeader("Accept") String acceptHeader) {
        logger.info("Serving resource for Accept header: {}", acceptHeader);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(genderRepository.findOne(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Model

package net.jkratz.bloodpressure.api.model;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import com.google.common.base.Objects;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(catalog = "jkratz", schema = "blood_pressure", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"title"})})
@XmlRootElement
public class Gender implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "gender")
    private List<User> users;

    public Gender() {
    }

    public Gender(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Gender(Integer id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Gender that = (Gender) o;

        return Objects.equal(this.id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equal(this.title, that.title);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id, title);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("id", id)
                .add("title", title)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

MVC Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- scan for beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.jkratz.bloodpressure.api" />

    <!--
    <bean id="contentManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false"/>
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
        <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    -->

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.jkratz</groupId>
    <artifactId>blood-pressure-tracker-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bp-tracker-api</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <issueManagement>
        <system>Github</system>
        <url>https://github.com/jkratz55/blood-pressure-tracker-api/issues</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/jkratz55/blood-pressure-tracker-api.git</url>
    </scm>

    <!-- properties -->
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>3.2.5.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
        <org.springdatajpa-version>1.7.0.RELEASE</org.springdatajpa-version>
        <org.hibernate-version>4.3.6.Final</org.hibernate-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.2</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.7</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <!--dependencies -->
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springdatajpa-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON & XML -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>17.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- build settings -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>blood-pressure-tracker-api</finalName>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed the same problem yesterday. Once updated the spring version to "4.1.0.RELEASE", I started to see "application/json" not acceptable problem. All the previous spring versions work fine. I do not know how to resolve this yet, but hopefully some one can give the answer. Thanks ...

If I can find any meaningful solutions, I will update.

Comment: I ran into this as well. I downgraded from 4.1.0 to 4.0.5 and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

try to change Jackson dependencies in your pom.xml by this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You don't need jackson-core or jackson-annotations if you declare jackson-databind - they are brought in transitively. (At least for v2.8.7)